# Files exist, but "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" 20.04

Tags: 20.04, libraries, shared-library

I'm trying to run a game (PRIME, an old Rougelike found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160317071539/http://pesky-reticulans.org/)) and after downloading the 64 bit linux version, and going to run it, I get this error response:

> ./prime: error while loading shared libraries: libsigsegv.so.2: cannot
> open shared object file: No such file or directory

***Now, I've checked that I've got that file in my library, and it's up to date.** The [last time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215432/18-04-shared-libraries-no-such-file-or-directory-for-libraries-verified-to-e) I asked this question I was able to solve it simply with a sudo-apt-update, sudo-apt-upgrade. That isn't working this time.*

(The italicized note above is technically a mistake. I did have that file, but not the i386 version. Take a look at the accepted answer and my comments to see how we discovered that!)

My real item is this, though: Shared library problems are a pretty common error, it seems, and although the library in question changes, the other common issue is that the library exists, but for some reason the executable (or the user?) can't find it?

This is also not the first time I've had this issue on this system.

Is there a general solution or approach to shared library problems?

I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350068/where-does-ubuntu-look-for-shared-libraries) using `ldconfig` but I haven't been able to get it to work.

output of `ldd ./prime` in the directory with that executable

```
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f03000)
libsigsegv.so.2 => not found
libnoteye.so => ./libnoteye.so (0xf7e4f000)
libncurses.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 (0xf7e26000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0xf7e00000)
libpanel.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpanel.so.5 (0xf7df9000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7c1b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7b16000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7af7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7908000)
libSDL-1.2.so.0 => not found
libSDL_image-1.2.so.0 => not found
liblua5.1.so.0 => not found
libutil.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0xf7901000)
libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0 => not found
libSDL_net-1.2.so.0 => not found
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0xf7894000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf7876000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7870000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f04000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0xf77f3000)
libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0xf77b7000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf7666000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf7637000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf7631000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf7629000)
libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0xf760a000)
```

Comment: Is libsigsegv2 on your system? `ldconfig -p | grep libsigsegv2`

Comment: It is! I checked in Synaptic, and running your command gets me this:

 libsigsegv.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsigsegv.so.2

Comment: I'll try to check this tomorrow.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't get it started in my ubuntu only in Debian.

Comment: Could you add output of `ldd ./prime` .I'm not familiar with it, if it is script check the program it uses. Also try force reinstalling of that lib `sudo apt --reinstall install libsigsegv2`

Comment: found my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `ldd`, it is clear that `prime` is a 32bit/`i386` build. It requires dependencies from same architecture. We may confirm too using:

```
file ./prime
```

We search for each missing library file using `apt-file` (if installed, be aware it downloads large indexes) or https://packages.ubuntu.com for corresponding package then install it.

```
sudo apt install libsigsegv2:i386 \
libsdl1.2debian:i386 libsdl-image1.2:i386 liblua5.1-0:i386 \
libsdl-mixer1.2:i386 libsdl-net1.2:i386
```

Comment: Okay! This worked.

Comment: Could you tell the missing libs were i386 because the other libs that were listed were i386? @user.dz

Comment: @JasonMehmel yes, also you can confirm with `file ./prime`

Answer (score 0):

For a so called 64-bit application prime needs a bunch i386 libaries. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` afterwards `sudo apt update`

Make sure the not founding libaries are installed for 64-bit and 32-bit.

You can found the relevant packages with apt-file search missing file.

maybe you have to  install it `sudo apt install apt-file` and `sudo apt-file update`

[image]

[How to use apt-file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Comment: Doing the i386 add didn't work for me. Will try installing lib files bit by bit.

Did you have to add a bunch of libraries to get it going?

Also, the list from ldd shows lib files that are *definitely* installed. Which is what leads me to the main question. Is it that the executable isn't able to see it somehow?

It isn't that I'm missing the lib files, it's that the program can't find them when it tries to run.

Comment: Used apt-file to try to examine for the lib files. libsigsegv.so.2 was one I could find, but tried updating it anyway, no dice.

Comment: did you have any missing libraries when you first tried to run this program?

Comment: @JasonMehmel, no on ubuntu I had no multiarch and I get some stupied message file  not found, when I try to start it. After adding multiarch, I started the game with strace and saw, it was querring 32-bit libs. `file -l ./prime` shows much old stuff so I started to install missing libs in 64-bit and 32-bit.

Comment: That lines up with the other answer we found!